# Any equivalent of Entitled Capacity in x86 systems

Tags: unix, ibm

I've been reading a lot about IBM POWER systems lately and I've been wondering if there is any equivalent to their Entitled capacity concept in x86 architecture. Basically allowing virtual partitions to use more CPU cores than they've been assigned loaning from a shared CPU pool.

Comment: That wouldn't be a feature of the actual CPU, more of the hypervisor/kernel, and in both cases yeah there's functional-equivalents but you'd need to narrow down the details a bit more before we could tell you how to do this - but yeah, it's very do'able.